# enumerate with 3 type of shortlst

Tags: lists, enumerate

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol,shortlst}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\columnsep}{35pt}%% Space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}%% Width of rule between columns

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\roman{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{{\theenumiii}}

\renewenvironment{shortenumerate}[1][\hbox to \shortitemwidth{\hfil}]{%
    \setlength\shortitemwidth{45pt} %% Balaji added
    \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\let\endsh@rtitem\relax\else
    \ifx\item\sh@rtitem\sh@rtnesterr\let\endsh@rtitem\relax\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
    \settowidth\shortitemwidth{#1}%
    \list{}{\addtolength\leftmargin\itemindent
        \addtolength\leftmargin{-\labelwidth}%
        \addtolength\leftmargin{-\labelsep}%
        \addtolength\leftmargin{-7pt} %% Balaji added
    \addtolength\labelsep{-5pt} %% Balaji added
    \addtolength\itemsep{0pt} %% Balaji added
        \setlength\itemindent\z@}%
\item\relax
\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
\let\endsh@rtitem\noindent
\let\item\sh@rtitem
\usecounter{\@enumctr}%
\def\@itemlabel{\csname label\@enumctr \endcsname}%
\fi\fi\ignorespaces}%
{\endsh@rtitem\endlist}
\makeatother   
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{document}

\section{shortlist with 3 enumerate}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The values of should be about $-4$, $-3$.  The graph of $y=x$ should approximate a line of gradient~2.

\item The values of should be 0. The graph of $y=x$ is a parabola crossing the $x=-2$ and $x=2$.

\item
\begin{shortenumerate}
\item 3
\item $-7$
\item 5
\item $-3$
\item $\frac{1}{2}$ 
\item 0
\end{shortenumerate}

\item
\item
\begin{shortenumerate}
$4 +h$, $f'(2) =4$
$2h +3$, $f'(0) =3$
$-6 +h$, $f'(-1) =-6$
\end{shortenumerate}

\item
\begin{shortenumerate}
\item $2x +h -6$, $=2x -6$.
\item It is a concave-up parabola with $x=0$\break and $x=6$.
\item $f'(0) =-6$, $f'(6) =6$.
\item $f'(3) =0$.
\end{shortenumerate}

\item
\begin{shortenumerate}
\item $8 -2x -h$, $=8 -2x$
\item It is a concave-down parabola with $x=0$ and $x=8$.
\item $f'(0) =8$, $f'(8) =-8$.
\item $f'(4) =0$.
\end{shortenumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get Arabic list first and alpha list second and roman list third. Between arabic number and alpha number is fixed space. alpha number and roman number is also fixed space. `\break` is also not working in the `\item`. The alignment is shown below:

Expected output is:
[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't correspond to the code, and I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Bernard: The image is expected output and not related code. First arabic list print, second alpha list print, third roman list print. Expect labelwidth separation is fixed for Arabic (Example arabic labelwidth=9pt, Alpha labelwidth=7pt, roman labelwidth=5pt).